# Proving that a function is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $g$ a increasing function, and $f$ integrable with respect to $g$ in $J=[a,b]$ proof that $|f|$  is integrable with respect to $g$

By definition if $f$ is integrable with respect to $g$, for every partition $P$ of $J$ and for every $\epsilon>0$ exists $I$ in $R$ such that if $Q$ refine $P$ then $|S(Q,f,g)-I|< \epsilon $ 
$$|S(Q,f,g)-I|= \sum^{n}_{j=0}f(\lambda_{j})(g(x_{j}-x_{j-1}) $$ then

$$\sum^{n}_{j=0}|f(\lambda_{j})|(g(x_{j}-x_{j-1}) \geq \sum^{n}_{j=0}f(\lambda_{j})(g(x_{j}-x_{j-1}) $$

but i don't know how to do

$$\epsilon \geq \sum^{n}_{j=0}|f(\lambda_{j})|(g(x_{j}-x_{j-1}) $$

somebody can help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is integrable with respect to $g$ on $[a,b]$, there exists a $\delta$ such that for all partition $P$ finer than $\delta$, we have
$$U(f,P,g)-L(f,P,g)<\epsilon$$
where $U$ and $L$ are the [Darboux sums](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Darboux_sums).

This equals to $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (\sup_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{f(x)\} - \inf_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{f(x)\})(g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i))$$

for $x_i$ chosen in $P$.

Now consider $\delta_i = \sup_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{|f(x)|\} - \inf_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{|f(x)|\}$.

- If $\sup_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{f(x)\}$ and $\inf_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{f(x)\}$ are both positive or negative, or at least one of them is equal to zero, then $\delta_i$ is equal to the difference of them.
- If $\sup_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{f(x)\}$ and $\inf_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{f(x)\}$ are positive and negative respectively, then $\delta_i$ is strictly smaller than the difference of them.

Anyway, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (\sup_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{|f(x)|\} - \inf_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{|f(x)|\})(g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i)) \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (\sup_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{f(x)\} - \inf_{x_i\le x \le x_{i+1}}\{f(x)\})(g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i)) < \epsilon$$

Since $g$ is non-decreasing, we conclude that $|f|$ is integrable w.r.t. $g$.